# My website not showing products on front page

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks

Any help will be highly appreciated. My website https://muzikhausberlin.de is not showing products on the front page, however on other pages products working fine but I can't see any images in a block and on front page content section.

Moreover there is no widget on my website.

Thank advance for support.

Answer (score 1):

Please check there will be some option on products section, where you can select a product as is_featured..

Alternatively, you can make a new featured products category, suppose its id is 4

In Magento admin panel go to CMS> Pages>Home page.

```
{{block  type="catalog/product_list" category_id="4"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

In case you want to control the number of columns in product listing, please use the following code:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="4" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Where the column_count value is the number of columns.

Navigate to System->Permissions->Blocks.

Click on the Add new block button.

Specify your Block Name, which is: catalog/product_list.

And allow the Block using the YES/No Dropdown list..

Then reload the home page and check...

Comment: great helpful featured products category working fine. but still if you visit my webiste you will see a block name "Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List" but i don't have at backend

Comment: Great. Enable path hints... then i'll check which block you're talking about or share screenshot...